# Using Ubuntu to Reinstall Windows 10 Using GRUB2 and no USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I want to remove Ubuntu 20.04 from one of my computers and reinstall Windows 10.

I have downloaded the Windows-1909.iso.

I do not have a USB drive that is large enough to use the Windows MediaCreationTool.

My village is in lockdown and I can not borrow anything from friends or visit the computer shop. I have no access to a Windows computer, just an Ubuntu computer and the Internet.

How do I proceed, to reinstall Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Reinstalling Windows 10 from Ubuntu

Windows can be installed to boot in BIOS, (Legacy), mode or in UEFI mode. I will describe each method.

**BIOS, (Legacy), mode, MSDOS Partition Table**

- Boot Ubuntu in Legacy mode.
- Using GParted, create a 8GB NTFS partition for the installer and a 50GB or larger partition for Windows.
- Mount the Windows ISO using `sudo mount -t udf /{Path to ISO}/Win.iso /media/iso`, Copy the contents of  `/media/iso/` to the 8GB partition.
- In Terminal run `sudo update-grub` to add the Windows installer to Ubuntu's GRUB menu.
- Edit the grub.cfg Windows menuentry, to add `ntldr /bootmgr` on the line after `chainloader +1`
- Reboot and select **Windows Recovery Environment** from the Boot menu.
- Proceed with Windows 10 installation as normal.

**UEFI mode, GPT Partition Table**

- Boot Ubuntu in UEFI mode.
- Using GParted, create a 8GB NTFS partition for the installer and a 50GB or larger NTFS partition for Windows.
- Mount the Windows ISO using `sudo mount -t udf /{Path to ISO}/Win.iso /media/iso`, Copy the contents of  `/media/iso/` to the 8GB partition.
- It should not be necessary to Update GRUB to boot in UEFI mode. (Please let me know if you find otherwise).
- Reboot, The Windows installer should start. At this point you can close the installer to open the GRUB menu.

**UEFI Notes:**

UEFI properties may vary among vendors.

It may be necessary to add Windows Recovery Environment menuentry by hand.

Some instructions for installing Windows recommend the ISO be extracted to a FAT32 partition. If there are problems using the ISO extracted to NTFS see: https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/windows-10-usb-media-linux.html

I was not able to install as UEFI mode from Legacy Ubuntu on GPT disk.