# Can't see live USBs on BIOS

Tags: usb, uefi, live-usb

I've an ASUS TUF Dash F15 fx516pm (UEFI system) running the latest version of Ubuntu.

I decided to sell it because I need money for college. Hence, I need to re-install windows ASAP.

The problem that I'm facing is that whenever I create a live USB, the Asus BIOS won't detect it. I've tried disabling fast and secure boot but nothing seems to work.

I have tried creating a live Ubuntu USB so that I could edit the root partition with "Startup Disc Creator" but no luck with it.
I've also tried making a live USB for windows from a Windows VM but that isn't getting detected either.

I'm out of options and I need to install it before monday morning. Any tip or advice is enormously appreciated.

Comment: When booting try pressing ESC, F9, F12, etc to select the USB disk. or else set the USB as first HDD in BIOS. You can also boot Windows ISO extracted to NTFS folder on disk, see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337487/using-ubuntu-to-reinstall-windows-10-using-grub2-and-no-usb

Answer (score 0):

Based on [documentation from Asus](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1013017/):

> Before booting the system from a USB flash drive or CD-ROM, please let your computer enters the BIOS configuration first, here you can [learn more about How to enter BIOS configuration](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1008829/). After entering the BIOS configuration, there are two kinds of BIOS screen which are UEFI mode and Legacy mode, please refer to the following steps in order.
>
> Boot the system from USB flash drive/CD-ROM in BIOS - UEFI mode. In UEFI mode, you are able to select and choose the item via Arrow Keys and Enter of keyboard, Touchpad or Mouse.
>
> 1. After entering the BIOS configuration, press Hotkey[F8] or use the cursor to click [Boot Menu] that the screen displayed.
> 2. Select USB flash drive/CD-ROM in Boot Menu that you want to use, then press Enter key to boot the system from USB flash drive/CD-ROM.

If the system still does not boot from the USB, then visit the Asus page for an alternate walk-through. If “nothing works”, then the ISO you downloaded and used to make the bootable media is probably bad.

Comment: Sorry, I explained myself incorrectly. What I mean by "Asus BIOS won't detect it" is that it doesn't appear on the Boot Menu. I've visited the page for alternative walkthroughs (even my case where USB doesnt show up on the Boot Menu). But it stil doesn't work. I'll try this afternoon with another USB.