# Can I create a bootable windows USB from live Ubuntu? If so how?

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, windows-10, usb-installation

currently my windows isn't booting so I need a Windows installation to fix it, but I don't have any pc to make one, so I'm using a software on my phone to turn the phone into bootable usb but it doesn't work with normal iso only hybrid ones like Linux, so I thought of using live Ubuntu to download the Windows iso and burn it to the USB, is this possible and how to do it, and what's the best Ubuntu version for it.

Comment: Best Ubuntu version is subjective. But for just downloading an ISO and writing it to a disk, any version will do. Of course, using something like SystemRescueCD would work just fine

Comment: If UEFI, you can boot the Windows installer from the Ubuntu disk without the need for a USB: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337487/using-ubuntu-to-reinstall-windows-10-using-grub2-and-no-usb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is this possible

Yes

> and what's the best Ubuntu version for it.

Does not matter.

> and how to do it,

Download the ISO. Put in a thumb drive and install [WoeUSB](https://github.com/WoeUSB) from software center. Or use:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tomtomtom/woeusb
sudo apt update && sudo apt install woeusb-frontend-wxgtk
```

> WoeUSB is a simple tool that enable you to create your own
> usb stick windows installer from an iso image or a real DVD.
> It is a fork of Congelli501's WinUSB.

Do double-check that you have selected the correct device before proceeding. And you do need a valid Windows license to activate  Windows. To get that from Linux use:

```
sudo cat /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/MSDM
```

Comment: So Ubuntu 12 is okay? Because it's the smallest one and WiFi sucks at downloading, thanks.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 12  so that does not count as Ubuntu ;-) Only 18.04, 20.04, 20.10, and 21.04 Plus 21.10 in a few days.  And any derivative. If you DO want to use an end of life you can but you need to download each software from the source and install it manually.

Comment: It's better to use a supported version of Ubuntu (e.g., 20.04 LTS).

Comment: "Because it's the smallest one and WiFi sucks at downloading" If that is an issue. Damn Small Linux is 40Mb. Making a bootable USB does not require Ubuntu. Help from AU does require it ;)

Comment: There is 16 and 14 in releases.ubuntu.com do these have only manual install?

Comment: Well I tried gparted live and it was a mess google crashed the browser couldnt download anything browser cerficate errors everywhere no file manager, that's why I wanted something big like Ubuntu