# How to install win 10 after Ubuntu 20.04 Lts?

Tags: grub2, windows-10, gparted

Ubuntu 20.04 is already in use, I want to install win 10, and keep Ubuntu.
Kindly, guide me on how I can install 'win pro' without bootable Pendrive or with bootable pendrive.

Comment: Don't think there is an easy pendriveless workaround. It seems unrelated to Ubuntu.

Comment: Hello. This is not a question about the Ubuntu OS. It is a question about how to install Windows. So .. It belongs on https://superuser.com/

Comment: Looking for an answer to such a question: How to restore grub after installing Windows 10(efi, uefi, mrb)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Comment: To install Windows from Ubuntu without using a pendrive see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1337488/43926

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to install Windows without destroying Ubuntu bootloader. Every operating system has it's own bootloader and after you install OS Y after installing OS X, OS Y will destroy your current bootloader. Even with linux, when you install Fedora after installing Ubuntu, Fedora will overwrite Ubuntu bootloader. To solve the problem, simply make a new partition, install Windows on it, then boot your computer into Ubuntu from a bootable flashdrive and use [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to recreate Ubuntu bootloader. I've done it myself dozens of times.

Comment: 'It's not possible to install Windows without destroying Ubuntu bootloader.' Yes you can if you install Windows to another disk and temporary detach your 'Ubuntu-disk' from powersupply and motherboard. That way Windows cannot mess with your Ubuntu system.

Comment: But this isn't something that people want to do.

Comment: You may be right. There are people that don't have the knowledge or ability to do this. There are also people who can do this with their eyes closed and one hand tied behind their back.

Comment: Right, but operating systems are and should be made so that people don't have to learn those things in order to install it.

Comment: actually i have created 450 GB partition for window using gparted on ubntu 20.04, and make a bootable pendrive of win10 using disks app in ubuntu, now problem is, when i inserted the bootable pendrive in HP laptop, it show no bootable device ... found. i have change my BIOS setting but still not working, kindly guide me.

Comment: now if I want to install Windows via terminal then how ?

Comment: this drive link show my bios setting

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sJfNUvGTABx-xa9CnParSOwT26Ke_82Q/view?usp=drivesdk , and this show error https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sQGPVbo8ghNOS0lrzAYmBMTJjHp_T81O/view?usp=drivesdk, and this one show my bootable pendrive with win 10 pro (usb hard drive sandisk) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sQGPVbo8ghNOS0lrzAYmBMTJjHp_T81O/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @ Vivek Like commented by other people this question doesn't belong on this site. Your question is how to make a Windows usb stick ( answer: with windows media creation tool ) and how to install Windows. This site is for questions about Ubuntu.