# Make a HDD partition bootable from Ubuntu live

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, mount, hard-drive

How can I make HDD partition work like a iso bootable for a Windows iso?

What I have:

-Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (on USB as a "Try Ubuntu")

-Partition of NTFS (500GB) (hard disk)

-Windows ISO downloaded to a another laptop

Goal: I want to install Windows on hard disk from one of the segment of 500GB. I mean slicing 500GB to 2 segments. Make 1 segment bootable by extracting .iso content to it. After extracting I would get Windows installation screen after the restart of Ubuntu live (from USB).

Comment: 1. Please tell us the brand name and model of your target computer; 2. You have another laptop. What is the operating system on that other laptop (Windows or Ubuntu or something else; which version)? 3. Can you store the Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on that other laptop too? - In that case you can create a Windows installer on the USB pendrive (overwrite the current Ubuntu live system). I know tools for that for Windows, Ubuntu (and other Linux distros) and I think also for MacOS.

Comment: 1. HP Probook 4545s 2. Windows 7 3. The other laptop does not belong to me, thus I would not want to store there any system change.

Comment: The issue is that the Windows ISO is not directly bootable. You have to extract it and for UEFI boot, it has to be in a FAT32 partition with boot,esp flags. But Microsoft has make .wim file over 4GB, so it cannot be in a FAT32 partition. Microsoft tools to create UEFI bootable FAT32 partition splits .wim file to fit on FAT32.  I have used a drive with a full install of Ubuntu in UEFI mode, created 6GB FAT32 partition, moved boot flag to that partition & extracted ISO, & booted installer to install to another drive. Then restored boot flag to primary FAT32 for UEFI boot of installed system.

Comment: It is much easier to install an operating system from 'another drive', not from the same drive as the target for the installation. Would it be an option to buy or borrow a USB pendrive (size at least 8 GB)? I was not clear, I intended to ask: could you **store only** the Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS **iso file** `ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso` (size 3.6 GiB) in the other computer?

Comment: I think what the OP proposes will work okay as long as the computer can boot UEFI. https://askubuntu.com/q/1337487/43926

Comment: I guess Cameron referred the solution. In the meantime I have installed Ubuntu to the hard drive and instead making a ntfs partitions for Windows I wonder if a Windows as a virtual machine in Ubuntu via Virtualbox would be a better solution. Would a virtual Windows boot as fast as from hdd hard drive if I have 500 GB HDD and 16 GB RAM? I want to use mainly Ubuntu but Windows for a couple of only Windows-based software. I do not like the time the dual boot is requiring

Comment: An important advantage with a virtual machine is that you can run it without turning off the main operating system. If the computer is powerful enough (CPU) and has enough memory (RAM), the performance of the virtual machine will be good. But according to the specs your computer is rather old (was delivered with Windows 7 which has passed end of life), so I am afraid that Windows may not perform well enough for you in a virtual machine.

Comment: I have used Windows 10 fine from hard drive.

Comment: My CPU is AMD A4-4300m apu with radeon(tm) hd graphics x2

Comment: It is easy to install VirtualBox and test how well Windows will work in it. How much RAM is there in the computer?

Comment: @sudodus 16 GB is my RAM

Comment: Good that you have 16 GB RAM. It helps a lot to be able to allocate a lot of RAM to the virtual machine; in this case maybe half (8 GB) should be fine.

Comment: @sudodus In the meantime I have installed oracle vm virtualbox and started the Windows 10 home 64-bit install. Everything went smoothly until oracle hanged when Windows was preparing the system for the first time log-in. I had no choice to shut down the virtual machine. Now Windows shows an error that the installation failed and I have to restart it again. Does it mean I have to delete all partitions in the virtual drive and make a new clean install and hope that this hang will not happen again?

Comment: I would make a new clean install and hope that this hang will not happen again. If it fails again I suggest that you modify something in the settings of VirtualBox. If still problems, you must decide when to abandon the route via VirtualBox (maybe the problem occurs because the computer is rather old), and try instead to make a dual boot system via the method suggested by C.S.Cameron (or get a USB pendrive and make a 'Windows installer USB drive').

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Ubuntu to Reinstall Windows 10 Using GRUB2 and no USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337487/using-ubuntu-to-reinstall-windows-10-using-grub2-and-no-usb)

Comment: @sudodus I made a new clean install and this hang did not happen again. This time I occasionally moved the mouse of laptop in order to avoid the screen saver and/or any automatic sleep and/or hibernation. Perhaps the hang was due to the automatic log-out or screen saver.

Comment: @karel, I guess so.

Comment: @Bushido, Congratulations and thanks for sharing your solution :-)