# How to Install Windows from Extracted ISO on NTFS Partition with Grub2"

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, mount, windows

I am running Lubuntu 23.04 on /dev/sda3, and it's working well. However, my Windows partition (/dev/sda2) is corrupted. As I don't have access to USB or DVD, I extracted a Windows 10 32-bit ISO to an NTFS partition (/dev/sda4) using gnome-disk-utility. Now, I want to boot from this partition to install Windows on /dev/sda2. My system uses Grub2. Can someone guide me on how to achieve this?

Note: I have tried this but it doesn't work (error: invalid signature):

```
menuentry "Windows 10 Installer" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos4'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root <UUID>
    chainloader +1
}
```

Comment: Does [this question and comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428568/make-a-hdd-partition-bootable-from-ubuntu-live) help?

Comment: @graham no it does't help

Comment: I'm not sure what option you used in `gnome-disk-utility`, which has image tools, but they're intended for Linux images; did you explore what was created? does it look like a valid/bootable image?  as whilst I don't understand what you actually did; I'd expect an invalid & unbootable image where *invalid signature* is to be thus expected.

Comment: Are you sure you have 32 bit Windows? And is Windows in UEFI or BIOS mode. If drive is MBR(msdos) it has to be BIOS boot, but Ubuntu will let you install in UEFI mode to MBR drives (it should not). UEFI & BIOS are incompatiable on same drive. Microsoft required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives starting with Windows 8 in 2012, so Windows 10 should be UEFI on MBR, not BIOS on MBR.You have to have several external drives, one live installer to repair Ubuntu, a Windows repair/recovery flash drive & several for backups or at least other devices for backup.