# Issues creating a bootable Windows 11 USB on Kubuntu (tried with Ventoy and with Manual BOOT and INSTALL Gparted)

Tags: boot, usb, gparted

When I did the bootable process with Ventoy, I ran into errors mentioning that boot manager is missing when booting from USB.

When I did the bootable process manually with GParted by creating BOOT and INSTALL partitions and copying the files, I ran into an error on installation mentioning "missing media drivers". I have an Intel i9 12th Gen. I tired to install Intel RST with installation but still failed to move beyond that error.

I tried with WoeUSB, but I always run into issues in making it bootable itself due to the whole un-mount thing that one needs to do (which I have tried and tried, but always failed).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To be clear you are trying to make a Windows install disk?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to create a Windows 11 installable USB Flash Drive

Comment: Then this is a question for a different site. Suggest you ask on this site https://superuser.com/

Comment: Using Ubuntu to install Windows is I think is on-topic here. mkusb, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive, will make a Windows install disk. using Kubuntu.  But you don't need a flash drive, See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337487/using-ubuntu-to-reinstall-windows-10-using-grub2-and-no-usb