# I was trying to dual windows and Linux using parted magic but my harddrive boot now won't work

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

Soooo basically
I used "universal usb installer 1982" and installed Ubuntu using the parted magic.iso, but i misclicked  accidentally formated my F:/ instead of my 4Gig USB stick
So then i restarted
And my harddrive boot just says"syslinux 4.07 EDD 2013-07-25 Copyright (C) 19994-2013 H. Peter Anvinet al"
I think i somehow made my harddrive boot   into Linux instead of windows but the Linux boot doesn't work?

The problem is that i have no other computers available to download windows into a USB

Comment: To answer this question, someone will need a remarkable amount of knowledge about your computer, which nobody here will have. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you’re using (1) the primary OS(es) that you use (which I will assume is a version of Windows) (2) what you *expect* to see when you boot your computer. With this, it may be possible for someone to offer some pointers.

Comment: You do not need a USB to install Windows if you have Ubuntu. See: https://askubuntu.com/a/1337488/43926

Answer (score 0):

@Allpep - The first thing you have to do is to stop using 8 year old bits of software. (The usb installer) They're not compatible with the EFI Boot method with GPT partitions, they only used MBR Boot and that's basically been a non-thing on Windows for the last 5 years.

But, going further... The good and the bad:

1. Your data is probably still on this drive. (formats don't erase the entire disk)
2. There is no chance in heck that will boot.

If you boot a live Ubuntu live image you might be able to put it all back by installing and running the **testdisk** utility to recover the GPT partition table and other partitions. If it fails, you're no worse off than you were, which was wiped. Time to reload in that case.

For the love of God, upgrade your Ubuntu installation to the recent version once you get that sorted and stop using software that's nearly a decade old.