# How can I make a Windows 10 bootable USB on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: windows-10, startup-disk-creator

I want to make a bootable USB with windows 10 on it, but when I select the `.iso` file, it doesn't show up on Startup Disk Creator. I even tried another `.iso`, file but it doesn't show up either.

So how can I make a Windows 10 bootable USB on Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: You can use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). See also [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097560/woeusb-error-code-256-with-ntfs-formatted-usb/1098185#1098185) to a question at AskUbuntu about the alternative tool `woeusb`.

Comment: Windows boot disk using mkusb-plug: https://askubuntu.com/a/1274975/43926. Or If your computer boots UEFI, you can just extract the Windows ISO to an 8GB NTFS partition, and UEFI will boot it, see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1337488/43926 I have never gotten WoeUSB to work for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make Windows 10 bootable USB in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274878/make-windows-10-bootable-usb-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool called [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/download.html) that can hold several ISO (basically as many as the USB can hold) at the same time and will show a menu where you pick an ISO. And all you need to do in the future is replace an ISO with a new ISO. Not really useful for 4 or 8Gb sticks but a 32Gb stick can hold 3, 4, 5 ISO and a 256Gb stick that cost about 30 euro/USB can hold 40+ ISOs.

The [list of supported ISOs](https://www.ventoy.net/en/isolist.html) is very long and includes, besides Ubuntu/Debian, Redhat, SUSE, almost all spinoffs, also all Windows, and several ChromeOS. And then some. I have been using this for a couple of months now and can confirm Budgie 22.04, 22.10, Cinnamon 23.04, Kubuntu 23.04. Ubuntu Gnome 20.04, 20.10, 23.04, Windows 10 and Windpws 11 all work.

[image]