# Creating a Windows 10 Installation USB on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: system-installation, usb

On Ubuntu 22.04 I attempt to use "ISO Image Writer" to create a bootable USB drive from the file: Win10_22H2_English_x64v1.iso. This ISO file was downloaded from the Microsoft.com. On the attempt I get the error:

```
The last block was not fully written (-1 of 1,048,576 bytes)!
Aborting.
```

The USB drive is a Samsung HM250HI (232.9GiB). This happened in spite of my having used the Disks utility to reformat it to FAT.

Om my Ubuntu OS how can I get this USB drive to become an installation USB for Windows 10?

This is to be used to install Windows 10 on an old computer that cannot handle Windows 11 due to its processor not being supported. The computer is to be handed down to a family member how is not tech savvy enough to handle a Linux OS. Currently installed on this older computer is Pop_OS! 21.04.

Comment: You can use the tool [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) for this purpose. (It does not work to clone a Windows iso file.) You should check that the iso file was correctly downloaded. Check also that the USB drive is big enough, at least 8 GB (and it is if using the drive you mention in the question).

Comment: Only a few Linux tools work. Windows .wim file is over 4GB and therefore cannot fit on a FAT32 partition. Windows tools when making USB bootable flash drive, split the .win file into two parts, so they can be on a FAT32 formatted partition for UEFI boot.

Comment: This is what worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/1337488/43926 No special tools or downloads needed. Mkusb mentioned above also works. see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1274975/43926

Comment: The package wimtools contains wimsplit, which can be used to split up the too-big file in src when  on a fat partition.  Then the FAT on a USB will boot windows.

Answer (score 0):

So I can't comment on the error you're getting.  Tho it sounds liek a hardware error..can't read sectors or something.

I use unetbootin when usb image writer gives me issue.  You can get the link to unetbootin (and other suggestions) in this link from itsfloss
I want to say i've used it for windows iso before

https://itsfoss.com/live-usb-creator-linux/

Hope it helps:)

Comment: I need the result to be a Windows 10 OS installation USB flash drive. So any tool to create this from an .iso file that can only create Linux installation USBs are not useful.

Comment: Oops totally my failt, I swore I used it before but I must have misremembered.  Here is a guide that might be helpful.    https://itsfoss.com/bootable-windows-usb-linux/  Also just for reference, google is your friend.  Try searching make windows usb from linux. But the block not fully written sounds like a hardware thing, or maybe a bad iso if it fails at 1 gig

Comment: Reformatting just pretty much rewrites the file table and It does not do a sector write. You could try doing a write to all sectors on the drive to verify the sectors are good.  Using dd maybe?   Google?  Also the fs type is probably not important.  Usualy we're just talking writing a copy of the isofs to the drive, not copying the files over individually.  This would acount for why the result will usually show a drive of the same size as the iso, not reporting the ful size of the underling drive